# Is there any real danger to Google Analytics Spammers?

Tags: google-analytics

https://kinsta.com/blog/language-spam/

The google analytics spammers seem to be the new way to do spam online.

I was wondering, is that a security risk? Does this spam can have any bad effect on my website or is it just an annoyance that renders one particular part of Google Analytics less useful?

The question comes from the simple question of what is it gain from that spamming. You spam only maybe one person with a dumnb message. Not very useful. So I'm thinking that this spam must have another use, and that other use might be having an ill effect on the server or on the users. And that's what is scaring me to ask the question about a security risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessarily a security risk, rather than simply a nuisance. There are always things you can do to help prevent bots/crawlers... But when it comes to language spam I would say it is much more important from a marketer's perspective than a performance/dev side.

I have seen brand new websites with over 50% of the traffic from language spam. Talk about not very useful data. If you are tracking conversions as a business it is important to have as accurate and clean data as possible, otherwise it just makes your life harder. You can use filters or advanced segments to easily fix this.

What have they to gain? Peter Velchev from Dowser [explains it well](http://dowser.org/block-secret-google-com-referral-spam-google-analytics/):

> The idea behind this is that once you see the URL of the
>   new visitor, you might be tempted to trace it back to its source. This
>   would in turn generate real visits to the hacker’s website, thus
>   pushing it up the rating ladder...